# Perfomance problem with Flatlist in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, design-patterns

### What I want

I'm trying to use a `FlatList` to render an **array of objects that comes from server**(I'm using Apollo and Graphql to get data from server), but I'm getting a message from console:

`VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {"contentLength": 2392, "dt": 4527, "prevDt": 2777}`

I followed the message and wrapped my `renderItem` in `React.memo`, I'm using functional components so I cant use `PureComponent` or `shouldComponentUpdate`, but after this the problem persist.

### What I have

#### Component structure

```sh
HomeScreen (responsible for obtaining the data from the server)
  └── ProductList (FlatList Wrapper)
          └── ProductListItem (renderItem)
```

#### HomeScreen.js

```js
// HomeScreen.js
function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  const {data} = useHomeScreenProductsQuery({}) // this hook get data from server with apollo useQuery method

  // just print something on console but it can do something more complex
  const handleOnPressItem = () => console.log('go to product')

  return (
    <ProductList
      horizontal
      numColumns={2}
      products={data?.collection?.products?.edges.map(e => e.node) ?? []}
      onPressItem={handleOnPressItem}
    />
  )
}
```

#### ProductList.js

```js
// ProductList.js
import React from 'react'
import {Dimensions, FlatList, View} from 'react-native'
import {ProductListItem} from '../ProductListItem'

function ProductList({
  products,
  horizontal = false,
  numColumns = 1,
  onPressItem = () => {},
}) {
  const getLayoutManager = () => {
    const layoutManager = {}
    if (horizontal) {
      layoutManager.horizontal = true
      layoutManager.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
      layoutManager.ItemSeparatorComponent = ProductListItemSeparator
      layoutManager.contentContainerStyle = {padding: spacing.base}
    } else {
      layoutManager.numColumns = numColumns
    }

    return layoutManager
  }

  const renderProductListItem = ({item}) => {
    const columns = horizontal ? 2 : numColumns

    return (
      <ProductListItem
        product={item}
        itemContainerStyle={{
          width: dimens.common.WINDOW_WIDTH / columns,
        }}
        columnWrapperStyle={{flexDirection: 'column'}}
        onPressItem={onPressItem}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      {...getLayoutManager()}
      // Pass a changing value to the `key` prop to update the columns number on the fly
      key={numColumns}
      data={products}
      renderItem={renderProductListItem}
    />
  )
}
```

#### ProductListItem.js

```js
// ProductListItem.js
function ProductListItem({
  product,
  itemContainerStyle = {},
  columnWrapperStyle = {},
  onPressItem = () => {},
}) {
  const price = product.pricing?.priceRange?.start
  const priceUndiscounted = product.pricing?.priceRangeUndiscounted?.start

  const getProductPrice = () => {
    if (equal(price, priceUndiscounted)) {
      // render a price formated with $ symbol
      return <TaxedMoney taxedMoney={price} defaultValue={0} category="h6" />
    }

    return (
      <>
        <View style={styles.priceContainer}>
          <Text category="c2" appearance="hint">
            Antes&nbsp;
          </Text>
          <TaxedMoney
            taxedMoney={priceUndiscounted}
            category="c2"
            appearance="hint"
            style={styles.priceUndiscounted}
          />
        </View>
        <TaxedMoney taxedMoney={price} category="h5" />
      </>
    )
  }

  const renderItemHeader = () => (
    <View style={styles.itemHeader}>
      // this is only a wrapper of react-native-fast-image library
      <Thumbnail source={product} />
    </View>
  )

  return (
    <View style={itemContainerStyle}>
      // component from @UI-kitten components library
      <Card
        onPress={onPressItem}
        header={renderItemHeader}
        style={[styles.row, columnWrapperStyle]}
      >
        {/*Card Body*/}
        <Text
          category="c1"
          appearance="hint"
          ellipsizeMode="tail"
          numberOfLines={1}
        >
          {product.category?.name}
        </Text>
        <Text category="c1" ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={2}>
          {product.name}
        </Text>
        {getProductPrice}
      </Card>
    </View>
  )
}

export default React.memo(ProductListItem)
```

Comment: Look into https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check it. But I want to understand why I'm having this problem for this case. If u have any idea, I would like to know about it

Comment: Is an inherent limitation with flatlist itself. You could try and optimize the code by using useCallback() and useMemo() or if the data is coming from the server you can try adding pagination to the server response.

Comment: But I'm using `React.memo` for `rederItem`, the response has [pagination](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/overview/) thanks to Apollo and Graphql, any other optimization to remove this warning,

Comment: I'd suggest you try out recycler-list-view.